# Is there a way to treat an anchor tag popup as a modal dialog box, where you can simply click outside of it and it would go away?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

The idea is I'll have a popup window triggered simply by, for example,

`<a href="http://blah/" target="_blank">Link</a>`

When the user clicks this, instead of popping up in a separate browser window, I'd like it to pop up in a sort of jQuery modal dialog box - the idea is that I want the user to be able to click outside of this pop up to close out of it.  I can't seem to find a way to do this.  Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: You need to load in the content on the modal via AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load content in an iframe, something like that:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CGmGc/)

```
$('a[target=_blank]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $iframe = $('<iframe/>', {
        src: this.href
    }),
        $popup = $('<div/>', {
            class: 'popup'
        }).append($iframe);
    $popup.appendTo('body').focus().on('click', function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Would it be possible to put this script inside my anchor tag, within "onclick"?  That's ideally what I need.

Comment: inline script is never a good solution! So what is you issue using jquery to set handler? You could use more specific selector if it is your problem. If online script is your 'only' solution, you could just set snippet inside a function passing element as parameter and call this function with onclick attribute

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**
`$('a[target=_blank]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
var v = window.open(this.href);window.focus = function() { v.close(); }`

Comment: Wouldn't this just open a new internet browser window?

Comment: this will close child window when you go to parent page